# Declaration char * VS (char *) in C

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

I need to understand the difference between the two kinds of declarations:

```
char *ptr ; 
(char *) ptr = ptr1;
```

Comment: One compiles. One does not. This is something you easily could have discovered by just trying to compile them.

Comment: Where did the second line `(char *) ptr = ptr1;` come from?  It is not a declaration.  It is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one declaration

```
char *ptr ;
```

The expression statement

```
(char *) ptr = ptr1;
```

will not compile because in the left side there is used a temporary object not an lvalue due to the C form of casting.

Maybe you mean the following

```
char ( *ptr ) = ptr1;
```

In this case it is indeed a declaration and is the same as

```
char *ptr = ptr1;
```

Where a difference exists is the following example

```
char * p[N];
```

and

```
char ( *p )[N];
```

The first declaration declares an array of N elements of the type `char *`. 
The second declaration declares a pointer to an array of the type `char[N]`.